# ajax call using PHP and Javascript

Tags: ajax

Hi I'm trying to cal a server script on my local machine using Wamp server and the following code

```
var request = $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pay.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "stripeToken" : token,
            "firstName" : firstName,
            "lastName" : lastName,
            "email" : email,
            "price" : price
            }
    });
```

As you will see the script being called is pay.php, Ive tried a few things to sort this such as changing the URL and the dataType but still no joy. Is there something obvious I'm missing here, or do you require more code to help with this. I getting  a 'failed to call pay.php to process the transaction' error as a result of the following code:

```
 request.done(function(msg)
    {
        if (msg.result === 0)
        {
            // Customize this section to present a success message and display whatever
            // should be displayed to the user.
            alert("The credit card was charged successfully!");
        }
        else
        {
            // The card was NOT charged successfully, but we interfaced with Stripe
            // just fine. There's likely an issue with the user's credit card.
            // Customize this section to present an error explanation
            alert("The user's credit card failed.");
        }
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus)
    {
        // We failed to make the AJAX call to pay.php. Something's wrong on our end.
        // This should not normally happen, but we need to handle it if it does.
        alert("Error: failed to call pay.php to process the transaction.");
    });
```

Comment: Try debugging a bit more - for starters, try displaying the `textStatus` in the alert; also use the Inspector from your browser to see the request / response.

Comment: not sure how you mean, sorry

Comment: In the request.fail function, you get a parameter called `textStatus`. It may contain useful information as to why the request failed (e.g. 404 Not Found or 500 Server Error). Try showing that instead of a custom error message, while debugging (you could change the message to `"Error: failed to call pay.php to process the transaction. Please report the following error: " + textStatus"`.

Comment: Looks like the JSON returned by your PHP script might not be valid. Can you add the output of the script? I think you can get it from `jqXHR.responseText`.

Comment: Sorry do you mean the code for it?

Comment: No, I mean the output of the `pay.php` script. You are setting the `data` type of the output to `json`, so your PHP script should return some JSON, right?

Comment: sorry not sure how to do that, I'm a newb

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I solved by correcting the path the Stripe.php in pay.php.

1. In buy-controller.js, change the datatype in ajax from json to text.
2. Be sure the path to Stripe.php.

In a higher version, you must include init.php.